# Get current year of the 12 month with month wise count data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a query to get the 12 month of name and I also want month wise count for the `UserLogin`. I want to show month wise report in bar chart. So I need to create a query in SQL Server. But with my query I am not getting the expected 12 month and count. I'm always getting 1 count in all month.

Here this is my query can you please help me where is mistake =>

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(dateadd(MM, T.i, getdate()),'MMMM') AS DateColumn, 
    uf.TotalCount
FROM 
    (VALUES (-11),(-10),(-9),(-8),(-7),(-6), (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0)) AS T(i)
OUTER APPLY
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(datepart(MM, InsertDateTime)) AS TotalCount
     FROM 
         User 
     WHERE 
         DATEDIFF(mm, InsertDateTime, DATEADD(day, T.i, GETDATE())) = 0  
         AND IsLogin  = 1) uf
```

This is my data in the table:

```
UserId | IsLogin | InsertDateTime
-------+---------+---------------------------
 1         1        2017-08-22 16:12:46.713
 2         1        2017-08-22 16:50:55.789
 3         1        2017-07-10 16:12:46.713
 4         1        2017-07-10 16:12:46.713
 5         1        2017-06-21 16:12:46.713
 6         1        2017-06-04 16:12:46.713
 7         1        2017-06-05 16:12:46.713
 8         1        2016-09-05 16:12:46.713
 9         1        2016-09-05 16:12:46.713
 10         1        2016-10-05 16:12:46.713
 11         1        2016-11-05 16:12:46.713
```

This is my current output:

```
  DateColumn  |  TotalCount
  ------------+--------------
  September        1
  October          1
  November         1  
  December         1 
  January          1
  February         1 
  March            1
  April            1 
  May              1
  June             1 
  July             1 
  August           1
```

My expected output should be:

```
DateColumn  |  TotalCount
------------+--------------
January          0
February         0 
March            0
April            0 
May              0
June             3 
July             2 
August           2 
September        0
October          0
November         0  
December         0
```

Please tell me where is my problem in query. thanks

Comment: @marc_s can you please suggest me where is problem in query? please

Comment: You're offsetting by `day` in your apply rather than `month` with your `dateadd` call.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you mean i need change just like this dateadd(mm, T.i, getdate()) right??

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this way my count is come correct but month is not come correct way so for that where my mistake do you know?

Comment: Well, I'd prefer `month` over `mm`. I could never understand people's penchant for the abbreviated component names when the actual component names aren't long and make the code *far* more readable. But yes, in essence. At the moment, your apply, for all 12 rows, is finding values that occur within the same month as the last 12 days.

Comment: After switching `day` to `month`, I get the correct results here. In my tests, the results come in a different order to that shown in your expected output, but since you haven't specified an `ORDER BY` clause, that's got to be expected.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this. [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/WCSL32972)

```
DECLARE @StartDate SMALLDATETIME, @EndDate SMALLDATETIME;

SELECT @StartDate = '20170101', @EndDate = '20171231';

;WITH d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0))
  FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
)
SELECT 
  [Month]    = DATENAME(MONTH, d.d),   
  OrderCount = COUNT(o.UserId) 
FROM d LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS o
  ON o.InsertDateTime >= d.d
  AND o.InsertDateTime < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.d)
GROUP BY d.d
ORDER BY d.d;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some modification in your code

```
SELECT  FORMAT(dateadd(MM, T.i, getdate()),'MMMM') AS DateColumn,case when TotalCount is null then 0  else TotalCount end as TotalCount
    FROM (VALUES (-11),(-10),(-9),(-8),(-7),(-6), (-5), (-4), (-3), (-2), (-1), (0)) AS T(i)

    OUTER APPLY
    (
       SELECT distinct Count(datepart(MM,InsertDateTime)) AS TotalCount
           FROM user1 
           WHERE Datediff(mm,InsertDateTime, dateadd(month, T.i, getdate())) = 0  and IsLogin  = 1
    ) uf
    order by DATEPART(MM,convert(datetime,FORMAT(dateadd(MM, T.i, getdate()),'MMMM') +'01 2017',110))
```

Output -

```
DateColumn  TotalCount
January     0
February    0
March       0
April       0
May         0
June        3
July        2
August      2
September   0
October     0
November    0
December    0
```

Comment: Yes it's very nice. but are you pass here '01 2017' static date so this every time get 2017 year for 12 month so here how can add dynamic year?

Comment: I used static date for completing date only, if you calculate dynamically then also same result will come. order by month is needed  so more calculation is unnecessary for adding dynamic year.

Comment: Hi i want here some suggetion from your side can i ask?

Comment: In where condition dateadd(month, T.i, getdate())  right now current month is 8 ok. so here T.i value take 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 it's ok. but -8 take mean is take 2016 year in the month so how can get only current year mont?

Comment: Try this in your where Datediff(DAY,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, InsertDateTime), 0), dateadd(month, T.i, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) = 0

Comment: still i am also getting 2016 year in month sep,oct,nav,dec.. i want this month from current year so can you please help me or give me some hit

Comment: what are you trying to say? please share expected output so that i can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152614/discussion-between-edit-and-anagha).

Comment: i have edit my table data. right now in my table also 2016 years data is store so right now current year sep month is not coming ok so with my query take the sep month data of 2016 year. but i want sep month take 2017 year.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your query something like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT FORMAT(dateadd(MM, T.i, getdate()), 'MMMM') AS DateColumn --, uf.TotalCount
FROM (
    VALUES (- 11)
        ,(- 10)
        ,(- 9)
        ,(- 8)
        ,(- 7)
        ,(- 6)
        ,(- 5)
        ,(- 4)
        ,(- 3)
        ,(- 2)
        ,(- 1)
        ,(0)
    ) AS T(i)
) A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT datename(month, calcdate) datecol
    ,count(*) #trxns
FROM EmployeeMTDResults
WHERE calcdate BETWEEN '2017-03-01'
        AND getdate()
GROUP BY datename(month, calcdate)
) b ON (b.datecol = a.DateColumn)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Another Approach:

with cte as(select 0 as n
union all
select n+1 from cte
where n<11)

select DateColumn,isnull(cnt,0) 'TotalCount' from (
select DATENAME(MONTH,dateadd(mm,n,'2000-01-01'))DateColumn from cte)x
left join 
(
select DATENAME(MONTH,InsertDateTime)DateColumn1 ,count (DATENAME(MONTH,InsertDateTime)) cnt from User t
where InsertDateTime>='2017-06-04 16:12:46.713' and InsertDateTime<=getdate()
group by DATENAME(MONTH,InsertDateTime)
  ) y on x.DateColumn=DateColumn1
```

Comment: with your solution i am getting only current month data can't getting onther month data so please can give me some hint how can do that all year in month data in query